# Fluent NHibernate mapping a class without virtual properties

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm building my own membership provider using nhibernate.  The MembershipUser class is a surprisingly difficult thing to shoehorn into an nhibernate mapping, primarily I think because the base properties and methods are not all virtual.  My user class is defined as:

```
public class nhMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public new virtual Guid ProviderUserKey { get; set; }
    public new virtual DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Application { get; set; }
    public new virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public new virtual bool IsOnline
    {
        get
        {
            var UnitOfWork = new nhUnitOfWork();
            return UnitOfWork.UserIsOnline(this);
        }
    }
    public new virtual bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<nhRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public new virtual bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public new virtual bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public new virtual string ResetPassword()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public new virtual string ResetPassword(string passwordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public new virtual string GetPassword()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    public new virtual string GetPassword(string passwordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to create my mappings, I'm getting this:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete conf
iguration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons colle
ction, and InnerException for more detail.

  * Database was not configured through Database method.
 ---> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used
as proxies:
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhMembershipUser: method Update should be
 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhMembershipUser: method GetPassword shou
ld be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhMembershipUser: method ChangePassword s
hould be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhMembershipUser: method ResetPassword sh
ould be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhRole: method set_RoleId should be 'publ
ic/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
nhApplicationServicesProvider.Entities.nhRole: method set_Name should be 'public
/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Build
s\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 227
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in d:\Build
s\FluentNH-v1.x-nh3\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:line 232
   at nhApplicationServicesProvider.nhSessionFactory.CreateDatabaseSchema() in C
:\Users\JHolovacs\Documents\Projects\nhApplicationServicesProvider\nhApplication
ServicesProvider\nhSessionFactory.cs:line 63
   at nhApplicationServicesProvider.Program.Main() in C:\Users\JHolovacs\Documen
ts\Projects\nhApplicationServicesProvider\nhApplicationServicesProvider\Program.
cs:line 13

  * Database was not configured through Database method.
```

It specifically mentions GetPassword(), ChangePassword(), and ResetPassword() which are, as far as I can tell, properly overwriting the base class with virtual methods.

Why am I getting these errors, and how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It specifically mentions GetPassword(), ChangePassword(), and ResetPassword() which are, as far as I can tell, properly overwriting the base class with virtual methods.

No, you didn't overwrite these methods, you've only hidden them.

NHibernate requires all non-private properties and methods to be virtual, otherwise it has no chance to intercept the calls on a proxy.

If you don't need that class to be lazy loaded just map your entity with `lazy="false"` and you won't need virtual members any more. If you need lazy loading, you can use a proxy interface with `proxy="ProxyInterface"`.

Comment: Wow I'm officially out of my comfort zone with this, but it sounds like the right answer.  I will try this out and respond back.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need a while back and used [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/Fluent-MembershipProvider.aspx) as a template.  It seemed to work pretty well.

I think the key for this is to NOT inherit from MembershipUser in your domain object, but provide a way to translate between your domain user and a membership user (I don't believe I changed this function at all):

```
    public MembershipUser GetMembershipUserFromUser (User usr) {
        MembershipUser u = new MembershipUser (this.Name, usr.Username, usr.Id, usr.Email, usr.PasswordQuestion, usr.Comment, usr.IsApproved, usr.IsLockedOut, usr.CreationDate, usr.LastLoginDate,
        usr.LastActivityDate, usr.LastPasswordChangedDate, usr.LastLockedOutDate);

        return u;
    }
```

Comment: blech... that seems to violate some principals of clean coding.  Do you know *why* I'm getting these errors?  If I have to work around it, so be it, but I'd really like to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure it does, but I did go into it with a goal of not allowing MS' idea of a MembershipUser to leak into my entities.  If you would prefer to inherit from MembershipUser I think cremor's answer will point you in the right direction.